# Django My form is not saving in django db ?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am newbie and after reading documentation of django . i made forms but my form is not saving to my db and not showing in my db . please help me i tried so many ways but still its not saving . i have drivers for this purpose i want to register them . but its not saving to my db . and I think its not posting data to my db. 
please help me .

**Views.py**

```
def driver_form(request):
    args = {}
    template = Template.objects.get(template_default__exact=1)
    template_page = template.template_alias + str("/rentacar/rentacar_driver_form.html")#sir this ?
    return render(request, template_page, args)




def driver_save(request):
    args = {}
    if request.POST:

        driver_firstname = request.POST.get('driver_firstname')
        driver_lastname = request.POST.get('driver_lastname')

        driver_save_form = DriverForm(request.POST)
        if driver_save_form.is_valid():
            new_driver = driver_save_form.save(commit=False)
            new_driver.driver_firstname = driver_firstname
            new_driver.driver_lastname = driver_lastname
            new_driver.save()
            template = Template.objects.get(template_default__exact=1)
            template_page = template.template_alias + str("/rentacar/rentacar_driver_form.html")
            return render(request, template_page, args)
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

**rentacar_driver_form**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<form method="POST" action="/rentacar/driver-save/">
{% csrf_token %}
<label>
  First Name<br>
  <input type="text" name="driver_firstname" required>
</label>
<br>
<label>
  Last Name<br>
  <input type="text" name="driver_lastname" required>
</label>
<br>

<input type="submit" class='btn btn-primary' value="Submit">
</form>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Forms.py**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django import forms
from rentacar.models import *

class DriverForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BookingApproval
        exclude = (
            'driver_firstname',
            'driver_lastname',
        )
```

Comment: Hi @aPEX1, what is the output for `print(driver_firstname)` and `print(driver_lastname)` in your terminal...and also for `driver_save_form`. Is `driver_firstname` some sort of object? Or None? (or something "falsey").

Comment: "POST /rentacar/driver-save/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0

Comment: That's a very odd code to be receiving..."302" - you may need to debug in your code a little more. What version of Django are you using? If it is 2/0 you'll likely need to use `if request.method == 'POST':` rather than the old defunct `if request.POST:`

Comment: @MichaelRoberts I am using Django 1.11

Comment: @MichaelRoberts [19/Aug/2018 23:45:35] "POST /rentacar/driver-save/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[19/Aug/2018 23:45:35] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 12367

Comment: try to check if the form is valid after "if driver_save_form.is_valid():" put a print("form is valid") and also check new_driver before saving, print(new_driver)... if the form is valid, and the object is there, and save is not working... maybe check your db settings, and if you can save any objects at all like from the terminal just try to save a User object or something

Comment: Exactly what @ReedJones says - start debugging and seeing what is empty/missing etc ... it looks like the `is_valid()` is returning false. What happens when you remove the exclude line from `DriverForm` ??

Comment: @ReedJones I debugged nothing printed in my terminal .

Comment: sounds like your form isn't valid... try printing the form errors print(form.errors)

Answer (score -1):

just change

```
if request.POST:
    ...
```

inside of the driver_save view to

```
if request.method == "POST":
    ...
```

Comment: still not saving

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem, if request.POST is not empty it's pretty much the same as request.method == post... also op is checking form.is_valid before trying to save so if thats the case op has a valid POSTed form

Comment: @ReedJones what should I do ? I didn't understand?

Answer (score -1):

Try changing:

```
driver_firstname = request.POST.get('driver_firstname')
driver_lastname = request.POST.get('driver_lastname')
```

to:

```
driver_firstname = request.POST['driver_firstname']
driver_lastname = request.POST['driver_lastname']
```

Comment: these do the exact same thing